# Trying to alter css of one div by clicking an outside link via jQuery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tested out the CSS manually to where if I apply

```
display: none;
```

then it does what I want, so if I could use jQuery to make this happen by clicking a link on the page, then I'd be set.

I've never altered CSS via jQuery before, so I'm just going to try and explain what I'm trying to do here.

I have

```
<a id="one" href="#">click</a>
```

and then

```
<h3 id="two"><a href="#">link</a></h3>
```

I want to be able to click the first link and then set

```
display: none;
```

on that h3 labeled 'two.'

I appreciate the help guys. This is my first question here, and I usually like to just research the stuff on my own, but I think I'm just missing something fairly similar here and figured I should just ask someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#one').toggle(function() {

    $('#two').hide();

}, function() {

    $('#two').show();

});
```

Comment: I think this will do it. Thank you.

Comment: I would use `$('h3#two')` it will be easy to remember when you look at the code - say - months later.

Comment: I also noticed you would like it to reverse the process, I will add this to my example now.

Comment: Oh nice. Simple enough. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `toggle()` in it's simplest form. Click to show, click again to hide.

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    $('#two').toggle()
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/RjKe8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    $("#two").hide(); // not quite display:none
})
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, is there an unhide function I could use or could I use toggle() with hide?